# caffe fast rcnn smoothL1layer implementation

Tags: caffe

I was reading the fast rcnn caffe code. Inside the `SmoothL1LossLayer`, I found that the implementation is not the same as the paper equation, is that what it should be ?

The paper equation:

[image]

For each labeled bounding box with class u, we calculate the sum error of `tx, ty, tw, th`, but in the code, we have:

[image]

**There is no class label information used. Can anyone explain why?**

And in the backpropagation step,

[image]

**why there is an `i` here ?**

Answer (score 0):

1. In `train.prototxt` `bbox_pred` has output size `84 = 4(x,y,h,w) * 21(number of label)`. So does [bbox_targets](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/roi_data_layer/layer.py#L100). So it is using all labels.
2. As for loss layers it is looping over bottom blobs to find which on to propagate gradient through. Here only one of `propagate_down[i]` is true.

Comment: For the 2 point, you mean it also calculates gradient of the input (bbox_target)?

Comment: no I meant it calculates gradient first then loops over to assign value to the appropriate bottom blob.